# Array / Vector as method argument

Tags: java, performance, vector

I have always read that we should use Vector everywhere in Java and that there are no performance issues, which is certainly true. I'm writing a method to calculate the MSE (Mean Squared Error) and noticed that it was very slow - I basically was passing the Vector of values. When I switched to Array, it was 10 times faster but I don't understand why.

I have written a simple test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Vector <Integer> testV = new Vector<Integer>();
    Integer[] testA = new Integer[1000000];
    for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++){
        testV.add(i);
        testA[i]=i;
    }

    Long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i=0;i<500;i++){
        double testVal = testArray(testA, 0, 1000000);
    }
    System.out.println(String.format("Array total time %s ",System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i=0;i<500;i++){
        double testVal = testVector(testV, 0, 1000000);
    }
    System.out.println(String.format("Vector total time %s ",System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));

}
```

Which calls the following methods:

```
public static double testVector(Vector<Integer> data, int start, int stop){
    double toto = 0.0;
    for(int i=start ; i<stop ; i++){
        toto += data.get(i);
    }

    return toto / data.size();
}

public static double testArray(Integer[] data, int start, int stop){
    double toto = 0.0;
    for(int i=start ; i<stop ; i++){
        toto += data[i];
    }

    return toto / data.length;
}
```

The array one is indeed 10 times faster. Here is the output:

Array total time 854 
Vector total time 9840

Can somebody explain me why ? I have searched for quite a while, but cannot figure it out. The vector method appears to be making a local copy of the vector, but I always thought that objects where passed by reference in Java.

Comment: How often did you run the comparison? Run each for-loop in your main method 10000 times and compare the median of it.

Comment: both Arrays and Vectors are objects and are passed by reference, so that is not a problem here.

Comment: Are you sure that it said to always use Vector and not to never use Vector?

Comment: I'm running the method 500 times each (and actually in my real code the MSE calculation is called much more often) and difference is really big.

Comment: Related reading: [Why is Java Vector class considered obsolete or deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated)

Comment: Apart from the microbenchmark being flawed: A method signature should hardly ever contain such a concrete type. In the method signature, you could just use `List<Integer>` (and with minor changes, it could be generalized to `Collection<Integer>` or even `Iterable<? extends Number>`). In any case: For *real* "brute force number crunching performance", there's nothing faster than an simple, plain `int[]` array (albeit not very flexible and OOP, but *fast*). There are some potential issues with boxing/unboxing as well (beyond the scope of a comment, you'll find infos on the web)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**I have always read that we should use Vector everywhere in Java and that there are no performance issues,** - Wrong. A vector is *thread safe* and thus it needs additional logic (code) to handle access/ modification by multiple threads So, it is slow. An array on the other hand doesn't need additional logic to handle multiple threads. You should try `ArrayList` instead of `Vector` to increase the speed

Note (based on your comment): **I'm running the method 500 times each**

This is not the right way to measure *performance / speed* in java. You should atleast give a **warm-up run** so as to *nullify* the effect of `JIT`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that's the eternal problem of poor microbenchmarking. The `Vector` itself is not **SO** slow.

Here is a trick:
add `-XX:BiasedLockingStartupDelay=0` and now `testVector` "magically" runs 5 times faster than before!

Next, wrap `testVector` into `synchronized (data)` - and now it is almost as fast as `testArray`.

You are basically measuring the performance of object monitors in HotSpot, not the data structures.

Answer (score 0):

Simple thing. Vector is thread-safe so it needs synchoronization to add and access. Use ArrayList which is also back-up by array but it is not thread-safe and faster

**Note:**
Please provide size of the elements if you know in advance to ArrayList. Since in normal ArrayList without initial capacity resize will happen intenally which uses Arrays copy

**And a normal array and ArrayList without initial capacity performances too varies drastically if no of elements is larger**

Answer (score 0):

Poor code, instead of list.get() rather use an iterator on the list. The array will still be faster though.